# Google Play Crashes after a successful (test) payment

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm implementing Google Play Billing API v3 in my App, and testing it with  [Google play static testing SKUs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static).

The Fllow is:

1. If item `A` had already been purchased jump to 3.
2. purchase `A`
3. Consume `A`

I call `startIntentSenderForResult()` as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Purchase):

```
Bundle bundle = m_billingServiceConnection.GetService().getBuyIntent(
                GOOGLEPLAY_BILLING_API_VERSION,
                m_packageName,
                productId,
                purchaseType,
                purchasePayload);

        if (bundle != null) {
            int response = bundle.getInt(RESPONSE_CODE);
            if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = bundle.getParcelable(BUY_INTENT);
                if (activity != null && pendingIntent != null)
                    activity.startIntentSenderForResult
(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
```

which shows google's payment dialog as expected. However, after submiting, **Google play crashes (the "X unfortunately stopped working" popup), and my `onActivityResult()` never get called**.

logcat shows nothing as my app continue running.

It is important to note that the purchase seemed to be completed succesfully as on the next fllow the item shown as purchased (and later is successfuly consumed)

Comment: Did you every solve this problem. I am having the same problem except onActivityResult() is being called.